# How to write a DataFrame into a MySQL table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Sorry if it sounds vague but can one explain the steps to writing an existing DataFrame "df" into MySQL table say "product_mysql" and the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please see [this databricks article : Connecting to SQL Databases using JDBC.](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

val df = spark.table("...")
println(df.rdd.partitions.length)
// given the number of partitions above, users can reduce the partition value by calling coalesce() or increase it by calling repartition() to manage the number of connections.
df.repartition(10).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(jdbcUrl, "product_mysql", connectionProperties)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ram!